# Error from Google Maps API in choroplethr

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, choroplethr

I'm having an issue using the reference_map argument with the choroplethr package. I'm getting a 403 error when I set reference_map to true. The map renders fine if set to false. I've never had any issues with this argument before, I have used it successfully several times in the past. I tried added my API key(although I'd never needed it before), and the reference_map arg still doesn't work. Any thoughts? Reproducible example below:

> library(choroplethr) library(choroplethrMaps) library(ggmap)
>
> ### register_google([API KEY HERE])
>
> data(df_pop_county)
>
> county_choropleth(df_pop_county,
>                     title      = "2012 Population Estimates",
>                     legend     = "Population",
>                     num_colors = 1,
>                     state_zoom = c("california", "washington", "oregon"), reference_map = TRUE)

Comment: Was able to figure this out today. My key was just set up to use the Google geocoding API and not the static maps API. Had to go into the developer console and set it to work with static maps.